# turnRight method does not work in Combination Lock program - java

Tags: java

I am suppose to write a program that create a 3 digit combination lock (with integers between 0 and 39) which will update the current position(which starts at 0) when the first number is turned right, the second to the left, and then the third to the right. It then checks whether or not the lock can be opened. I have everything complete, but when I run my JUnit test the part where its suppose to open fails which is not right. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the combolock class:

```
public class ComboLock {
    private int secret1;
    private int secret2;
    private int secret3;

    private boolean position0 = true;
    private boolean position1, position2, position3 = false;
    private int currentNumber = 0;
    private boolean validSoFar = false;

    /**
     * Initializes the combination of the lock.
     * 
     * @param secret1
     *            first number to turn right to
     * @param secret2
     *            second number to turn left to
     * @param secret3
     *            third number to turn right to
     */
    public ComboLock(int secret1, int secret2, int secret3) {
        this.secret1 = secret1;
        this.secret2 = secret2;
        this.secret3 = secret3;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the state of the lock so that it can be opened again.
     */
    public void reset() {
        position0 = true;
        position1 = false;
        position2 = false;
        position3 = false;
        validSoFar = true;
    }

    /**
     * Turns lock left given number of ticks.
     * 
     * @param ticks
     *            number of ticks to turn left
     */
    public void turnLeft(int ticks) {
        if (position1 == true) {
            currentNumber = ticks;
            if (currentNumber == secret2) {
                position2 = true;
            } else {
                position2 = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns lock right given number of ticks
     * 
     * @param ticks
     *            number of ticks to turn right
     */
    public void turnRight(int ticks) {
        if (position0) {
            currentNumber = ticks;
            if (currentNumber == secret1) {
                position1 = true;
                position0 = false;
            }
            if (position1 == true) {
                currentNumber = ticks;
                if (currentNumber == secret3) {
                    position3 = true;
                } else {
                    position3 = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the lock can be opened now
     * 
     * @return true if lock is in open state
     */
    public boolean open() {
        if (position1 && position2 && position3) {
            validSoFar = true;
        }
        return validSoFar;
    }
}
```

and these are my test cases:

```
public class ComboLockTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Random randomizer = new Random();

        int secret1 = 10;// randomizer.nextInt(40);
        int secret2 = 20;// randomizer.nextInt(40);
        int secret3 = 30;// randomizer.nextInt(40);

        ComboLock lock = new ComboLock(secret1, secret2, secret3);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean opened = false;
        boolean turningRight = true;
        while (!opened) {
            System.out.println("Enter number of ticks to turn to the " + (turningRight ? "right" : "left")
                    + " 0 - 39. Enter an invalid number to quit.");
            int ticks = in.nextInt();
            if ((ticks < 0) || (ticks > 39)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. The program will now exit.");
                return;
            }
            if (turningRight) {
                lock.turnRight(ticks);
                turningRight = !turningRight;
            }

            else {
                lock.turnLeft(ticks);
                turningRight = !turningRight;
            }
            opened = lock.open();
        }
        System.out.println("You opened the lock!");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ComboLock c = new ComboLock(1, 23, 5);
        c.turnRight(1);
        c.turnLeft(23);
        c.turnRight(5);
        assertTrue("Should open but not", c.open());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        ComboLock c = new ComboLock(1, 15, 22);
        c.turnRight(1);
        c.turnLeft(15);
        c.turnRight(22);
        assertTrue("Should open but not", c.open());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        ComboLock c = new ComboLock(1, 3, 7);
        c.turnRight(1);
        c.turnLeft(3);
        c.turnRight(7);
        assertTrue("Should open but not", c.open());
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        ComboLock c = new ComboLock(1, 9, 18);
        c.turnRight(1);
        c.turnLeft(10);
        c.turnRight(18);
        assertFalse("Should not open but did", c.open());
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        ComboLock c = new ComboLock(1, 19, 36);
        c.turnRight(12);
        c.turnLeft(19);
        c.turnRight(36);
        assertFalse("Should not open but did", c.open());
    }
}
```

EDIT: forgot to mention but the ticks mean the actual value of the combination (a guess basically)
EDIT2: formatted better.

Comment: If you're going to post code, please at least put in the effort to post *well-formatted* code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for input, the code as been properly formatted.

Comment: `turnRight` is wrong - it only ever takes into consideration `position0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`turnRight` is wrong, it only ever takes into account `position0`. It should be considering `position0` and `position2`, not `position1`

For example...

```
public void turnRight(int ticks) {
    if (position0) {
        currentNumber = ticks;
        if (currentNumber == secret1) {
            position1 = true;
            position0 = false;
        }
    }
    if (position2 == true) {
        currentNumber = ticks;
        if (currentNumber == secret3) {
            position3 = true;
        } else {
            position3 = false;
        }
    }
}
```